# Google Sheets Auto Fill Formula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am taking value from  another tab (Page 2) using Auto Fill formula in (Page 1)

```
=arrayformula(IFS(ROW(A:A)=1,"Total",A:A="","",TRUE,iferror(index(Page2!A:A,match(A:A,Page2!B:B,0)),"Missing")))
```

It's showing Missing instead showing value
But if I use I could get the expected result for A2 cell from Page1

```
=iferror(index(Page2!A:A,match(A2,Page2!B:B,0)),"Missing")
```

I need to match from another tab and fill in the current tab with auto fill

Comment: Please share a sample sheet with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFS` is not supported under autofill

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Total"; IF(A2:A="",,
 IFERROR(INDEX(Page2!A:A, MATCH(A2:A, Page2!B:B, 0)), "Missing"))})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Total"; IF(A2:A="",,
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Page2!B:B, Page2!A:A}, 2, 0), "Missing"))})
```